# Validate email adress of several inputs created by a jquery script

Tags: jquery, ajax, forms, input

My goal is to check an email during typing. It works with one input with the first script but I would like be able to use this with several inputs (.input_email_1, .input_email_2, .input_email_3...). Those new inputs are created with the second script.
Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Any tip ?

**Script 1**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var x_timer;  
        $(".input_email").keyup(function (e){ //key press 
            clearTimeout(x_timer); 
            var user_email = $(this).val();
            x_timer = setTimeout(function(){
                check_username(user_email);
            }, 1000);
        });                 

        function check_username(username){
            $(".input_email_result").html('<i class="fa fa-spinner" aria-hidden="true"></i>');
            $.post('check_email.php', {'username':username}, function(data) {
                $(".input_email_result").html(data);
            });
        }
    });
</script>
```

**Script 2**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        var i=0;
        $("#add").click(function (e) {
            i += 1;
            $("#items").append('<input type="email" class="form-control input_email_' + i + '" name="email[]">');
        });
        $("body").on("click", ".remove", function (e) {
            $(this).parent("div").remove();
        });     
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After append a html, add that html a keyup function to use it directly. On your add function :

```
$("#add").click(function (e) {
    i += 1;
    $("#items").append('<input type="email" class="form-control input_email_' + i + '" name="email[]">');

    $( '.input_email_' + i).on("keyup",function () {

        console.log( i +" item called");

        // call your check username function.
        // you can also add here delay.
    });

});
```

[jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8y14qdsf/12/)